# Clarification: Definition of moment / expected value - Measure Theory

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, expected-value

Given a measure space / probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ - one might think about $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \lambda)$, where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ - we define the **first moment** (aka. **expected value**?) for a stocastic variable, X, as $$\text{E\{X\}} =\int_\Omega x \space\text{d}XP(x).$$

Similary one would define the **k'th moment** as $$\text{E}\{X^k\}=\int_\Omega x^k \space \text{d} XP(x).$$

However right after this introduction I was given the following example - both by my professor and my book (combining the definition above with another result. I do not know which result):

> Let $X$ be a real-valued stochastic variable which has density $f$ with
>   respect to the Lebesgue measure. We see that
>   $$\text{E}\{X^k\}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^kf(x) \space \text{d}x.$$

My questions are:
Why do we now multiply by $f$ under the integration? It seems to me that both the definition and the example of the k'th moment are valid, but they are not identical, so what is going on? And if $k=1$ (meaning that we are looking at the first moment), which of the cases is then the expected value?

Comment: $dXP(X)$does not make sense.

Comment: Perhaps $P$ is the CDF and $f$ is the density, so that $\int_{\Omega}g(x)\; dP(x)$ and $\int_{/Omega}g(x) f(x) \;dx$ really mean the same thing?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Perhaps $XP$ is the measure $P\circ X^{-1}$. That said, I don’t know why integration is over $\Omega$. Even if it were, the integrand doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, The part after "d" is introduced in a very formal setting.
I usually think about $\Omega$ as $\mathbb{R}$ or a set $A$ and $XP(x)$ as a measure $\mu$ or the Lebesgue measure where the lowercase $x$ specificies the variable we are integration with respect to.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist, you are right. $XP$ is defined / introduced using the imagemesure among other things (if I remember correctly)

Comment: Then $XP$ is a measure on $\mathbb R$ and the domain of integration should reflect that. I suppose there is a sense you can identify $\mathbb R$ and $\Omega$ (maybe), but that just makes things needlessly confusing.

Comment: That is, either write $\int_\Omega X(\omega) dP(\omega)$ or $\int_{\mathbb R} x dXP(x)$. I don’t think it’s a good idea to mix symbols between the two.

Comment: I will keep that in mind for future questions / readings. However I still don't feel like i understand why there is a diffrence between the given definition and the example - i.e. why do we multiply by $f$ in the example and not in the definition if they both are equal to $\text{E}\{X^k\}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at, Properties section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem

Edit: (I hope I didn't misunderstand your question)
Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function (in our case the random variable) ($ \forall ;A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \  X^{-1}(A)\in \mathcal{F}$). Then, we get a probability measure $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mathcal{P}_X)$, $\mathcal{P}_X(A) = \mathcal{P}(X^{-1}(A))$. Then,
$$ \int_{\Omega}X^k(\omega)d\mathcal{P} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}x^kd\mathcal{P}_X $$
which can be shown with the definition of the Lebesgue integral. Then using the Radon-Nikodym theorem, there exists a probability density function $f = \frac{d\mathcal{P}_X}{d\mu}$, such that
for any integrable $g$, 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}g \ d\mathcal{P}_X = \int_{\mathbb{R}}g f\ d\mu$$
Substituting $x^k$ for $g$ we get the result.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however I am not quite sure which part of my question the properties are answering - would you mind providing some more (perhaps "overexplaining") details?

Comment: Shouldn't you say $X^{-1}(A)$ for each instance of $A^{-1}$? I suppose it's interpretable when there is a single random variable $X$. However, suppose you had two...

Comment: Corrected, thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailes provided. If I am not mistaken, you could say that "the two E{X} is equal because of how we can change measures, when integrating" (using the arguments used in your edit)?

Comment: Yes, you can take an integral with a given measure $\nu$, using $\mu$ instead by adding $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ to the integrand, provided that $\nu << \mu$