Calculating expected value in baby probability vs measure-theoretic probability
How does the baby probability definition of expected value agree with the measure-theoretic definition?
I am currently learning measure-theoretic probability using the book by Athreya and Lahiri (a really great book, IMO). But I am having trouble making connections with the baby probability definition of expected value.
Consider the following setup:

$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is a probability space
$X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable.
$P_X: B(\mathbb{R}) \to [0,1]$ is the function defined by $A \mapsto P(X^{-1}(A))$
$h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a Borel measurable function

Then in baby probability, one learns that
\begin{equation}
E(X) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x f_X(x) \, dx \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $f_X(x)$ is the probability density function for $X$.
But in measure-theoretic probability, we have:
\begin{equation}
E(X) = \int_{\Omega} X \, dP \tag{2}
\end{equation}
I am wondering how $(1)$ and $(2)$ relate to each other?
I think the Change of Variables Formula (p. 193, Athreya) might be helpful to addressing the question. This formula states that we have the equality
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega} (h \circ X) \, dP = \int_{\mathbb{R}} h(x)\, dP_X
\end{equation}
in the following commutative diagram:

Unfortunately, I am having trouble connecting the dots beyond this point.

(Note: Athreya does not use a commutative diagram, but I like commutative diagrams so I inserted it. If the term commutative diagram is not appropriate for this context, then that is my mistake.)
(Disclosure: I copied/pasted the answer by @egreg to draw the commutative diagram.)

This question also seems relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3670931/139123

your change of variables formula is wrong

@Andrew Could you point out more specifically what I did wrong in my change of variable formula?

"for simplicity assume $X$ is differentiable" has no meaning when $\Omega$ is an abstract space, nor would differentiability be relevant even if it made sense. Your change of variables formula is obviously wrong, your $h$ is arbitrary. If $h$ is identity, it's correct.

@Andrew Regarding the differentiability of X: (1) good point that it does not make sense for general $\Omega$ (2) I included this assumption so that $X$ would be guaranteed to have density function $f$. Regarding the impossibility of $h$ being arbitrary: Unless I have copied the theorem down incorrectly from Athreya p. 193, then I think $h$ only needs to be Borel measurable and $\int_{\Omega} |h(X)| dP < \infty$. This is also Theorem 1.6.9 in Durrett's textbook.

you copied down the formula wrong. The differentiability of X is completely irrelevant even if $\Omega=\mathbb R$. What matters is the law of $X$, nothing else.

@Andrew Thank you for pointing this out to me. I think the error was in the integrand of the first integral: I should have written $(h \circ X)$ instead of of $X$. I have edited my original question to reflect this change. Thank you again for pointing this out.

By change of variables, $$E[X]=\int x\,P_X(dx)\,.$$ If $$P_X(B)=\int_B f(x)\,dx\,,$$ then for every simple function, we certainly have $$\int \sum_{j=1}^n c_j \mathbf 1(x\in B_j)\,P_X(dx)=\int \sum_{j=1}^n c_j \mathbf 1(x\in B_j)f(x)\,dx\,.$$ By monotone convergence this holds for all non-negative functions, that is, $\int g\,dP_X=\int g(x)f(x)\,dx$ for every non-negative measurable $g$. This of course then implies $\int x\,P_X(dx)=\int xf(x)\,dx$.
Notice that this argument does not depend on any properties of the Lebesgue measure, and thus, $E[X]=\int xf(x)\,\mu(dx)$ if $\mu$ is a Borel measure on $\mathbb R$ and $P_X(B)=\int_B f\,d\mu$.
